# Python, How to generate new rows with first column + one of value in second column?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, multiple-columns

How to generate new rows with first column + one of value in second column?

```
I have CSV or TXT dataset such as:
    1 [6377, 7153]
    2 [22, 33, ........]
    3 [132, .......]
    4 [1, ......]
    
    I would like to generate new rows which are the first column + one of the value in the second column like:
    1 6377
    1 7153
    2 22
    2 33
    2 ...
    2 ...
    3 132
    3 ...
    4 1
    4 ...
```

Comment: It looks like you wanna explode the dataframe- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html

Comment: Welcome to SO, don't foret to provide code sample you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use df.explode().It transforms list like elements to rows

```
array1 = {'col': [['1223', '4233'], ['5343','343434']]}
df= pd.DataFrame(array1)
print(df)
#output
    col
0   [1223, 4233]
1   [5343, 343434]

df.explode('col')
#output

    col
0   1223
0   4233
1   5343
1   343434
```